# chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory

Tags: chroot

In the process of trying to rescue an unbootable Debian Jessie system, I get the following error when trying to chroot:

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

I have been googling around and it's supposedly related to a 64bit/32bit clash (chrooting from a 32bit into 64bit or vis a versa), yet I don't see how that could apply here since I am rescuing a 64bit system with a 64bit live-hybrid-Debian-USB-stick.

/bin/bash is in the chroot directory and so are the library depenencies, as per ldd.

Does anyone have an idea what is causing the error?

Below are my mount points, and an ls:

```
  # mount |grep mnt
/dev/mapper/centos_vh200-root on /mnt/vh2 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/vh2/boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
none on /mnt/vh2/proc type proc (rw,relatime)
devtmpfs on /mnt/vh2/dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=10240k,nr_inodes=414264,mode=755)
sys on /mnt/vh2/sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)


  # ls -l /mnt/vh2/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1029624 Nov 12  2014 /mnt/vh2/bin/bash
```

This is ldd output for bash:

```
 # ldd /mnt/vh2/bin/bash
      linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd49bcc000)
      libncurses.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007fad99f1a000)
      libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fad99cf0000)
      libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fad99aec000)
      libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fad99743000)
      /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fad9a13f000)
```

Terminal session:

```
  # mount /dev/centos_vh200/root /mnt/vh2
  # mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/vh2/boot/
  # mount -t proc none /mnt/vh2/proc/
  # mount -o bind /dev /mnt/vh2/dev/
  # mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/vh2/sys/
  # chroot /mnt/vh2/ /bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Show `mount` and `ls -l bin/bash` in chroot. Also whole terminal session will be helpful.

Comment: `ldd /mnt/vh2/bin/bash` is done outside chroot so it finds your live system libraries.  Look for libraries in `/mnt/vh2/` not in `/`.

Comment: Oh, right... that makes sense.  The libraries were missing, along with a host of other things that should have been in the `/lib` dir.  So, I rsynced from a backup and `chroot  /mnt/vh2/ /bin/bash` worked.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do I give you credit for this?

Comment: Answer added, just accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ldd /mnt/vh2/bin/bash` is done outside chroot so it finds your live system libraries. Look for libraries in `/mnt/vh2/` not in `/`.